# Printing long receipt pdf to fit on receipt paper

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, receipt

I want to print a very long PDF with a receipt printer (Epson TM-T88IV).
The PDF I want to print however is predefined (I cannot change how the file is produced).

When I want to print this PDF with the Receipt printer, it prints it very very small and the receipt is unreadable.

There is a large margin left and right. To me, it looks like the Receipt printer wants to print the PDF onto a very small area.

```
if (type == PRINTER_TYPE.RECEIPT)
        {
            settings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
            settings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = (new PaperSize("Roll Paper",(int)(80*0.254), (int)(297 * 0.254))); //PaperSize is taken from the Printer Settings multiplied with a hundreth of an inch
        }
```

I couldn't find anything related.

€dit:

After some testing and printing multiple documents. I found out that the PDF Documents that print correctly have a correct Size

This one prints correctly, everything can be read when printed:

[image: This one prints correctly, everything can be read when printed]

This one cannot, as it is only one large page (What I want to print  ):
[image]

Is it possible to ignore the height and let the printer print the whole page correctly?

Answer (score 1):

PDF pages have a fixed size, both width and height. The receipt printer is most likely shrinking the page down while preserving the aspect ratio to fit it onto the paper.

Without a way to change the PDF itself, including the layout, I'm afraid you won't be able to fit it in a legible way on to the printer.